# Reformatting a table based on duplicates in python

Tags: python, reformatting

I have a table with three columns as follows:

```
time  variable  value
t1    var1      x1
t1    var2      x2
t2    var1      x3
t2    var2      x4
t3    var1      x5
t3    var2      x6
```

I want to reformat this table in such a way as to have  unique time instants and to get the values of each variable at that instant as follows:

```
time  var1  var2
t1    x1    x2
t2    x3    x4
t3    x5    x6
```

I'm using Spyder IDE.

Comment: Which kind of python object is your table?

Comment: Ok, It's a numpy table. I'm migrating from matlab to python.

Comment: Have a look at Dataframes in the Pandas package. They are extremely versatile. I give it a good change they  do what you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks Elmex80s. I'm taking a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is easier to use a [dataframes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) from pandas library and you can solve it using the pandas pivot method as follows

```
df = pd.load_csv("yourfilename.csv")
df.pivot(index='time', columns='variable', values='value')
```

Comment: How does this work when your table has 4 columns or more?

Comment: it works the same, it orders the new columns horizontally